# Read compressed XML file inside ZIP and parse data as fast as possible

Tags: c#, xml, stream, .net-core

I am trying to read and parse an XML file inside of a ZIP archive as fast as possible. The XML file is roughly 85GB in size, so I know for a fact that I/O also plays a role here, as I need to essentially read 85GB total. However, reading 85GB on a 500 MB/s SSD, means I can do this in less than 3 minutes, if we ignore CPU, decompression, and so on.

As I cannot store the ZIP file nor XML file in memory, I've streamed the content, and it works really well. Reading and parsing 100.000 XML nodes/elements (which is roughly 450.000 lines of XML) takes about 10 seconds. Don't get me wrong: Reading 400.000+ lines of XML and parsing it in ~10 seconds is fast. But it's not as fast as I want.

Multi threading this is probably not an option, but I am interested in hearing, if it's possible to speed this up.

`_models` is just a `List<Model>` that I use to keep my objects in, which gets cleared once they're saved to the database.

````
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.Async = true;

    using (var stream = new ZipInputStream(File.OpenRead($@"C:\file.zip")))
    {
        // this is fine, as we know there is only 1 file in the ZIP
        stream.GetNextEntry();

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings))
        {
            reader.MoveToContent();

            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (reader.Name == "ns:ElementName")
                    {
                        await ExtractModel(reader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // await save to database
}

private static async Task ExtractModel(XmlReader reader)
{
    XElement el = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Model));

    var model = (Model)serializer.Deserialize(el.CreateReader());

    _models.Add(model);

    // save 100.000 models to database
    if (_models.Count == 100000)
    {
        //await save to database
        _models.Clear();
    }
}
```
````

Comment: You do a `new XmlSerializer(typeof(Model))` each time you call `ExtractModel`: why not do this once at class level and then re-use the same serializer? Also, you can do `var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { Async = true };`.

Comment: @BCdotWEB The performance gained from not newing up a new XmlSerializer was next to nothing. Even if I do that, all of the checks and calls inside of Main (even the one to ExtractModel) says < 1 milliseconds. So nothing is "taking too long", it's simply slow because of the sheer amount of data.

Comment: @MortenMoulder Have you used some sort of profiling tool like [CodeTrack](https://www.getcodetrack.com/) to know where does your code spend most of its time? If so, could you please share with us the results? Please also share with us the expected performance requirement. *But it's not as fast as I want.* << It is not a requirement.

Comment: @PeterCsala I did not use a profiling tool, no. But if I put down a breakpoint and step through it, I can see how long each line of code takes to execute. And we're talking < 1 millisecond for each one. If I put a break point at the beginning of the code in the while loop, and one at the `save to database` line, it takes ~10 seconds for it to reach it. Simply because it has to run the exact same code 100.000 times.

Comment: Tip: `as fast as possible` - don't use async file API then, use synchronous instead (even with `Task.Run`), it's slightly faster. There's a bug in .NET that makes whole async File API slow. You may also test and compare the performance to ensure.

Comment: @aepot I removed everything that was async so the whole model is now synchronous instead. I implemented a Stopwatch before and after testing, and the only difference was maybe on average about 0.5 seconds per 100.000. Still takes ~10 seconds. Thanks, though.

Comment: OK, maybe bottle neck is out here, you may also play with buffers size for streams. Then run CPU profiler and see what exactly takes a lot of time. Also you may develop double-buffer mode. While you filling one `List` of 100k, you may dump already filled to DB at the same time. Then change the lists 2nd fill, 1st dump, etc. Async/concurrent work probably can be fine here, maybe with producer/consumer programming pattern. If you filling exactly 100k or less you may use arrays instead of lists with power of `ArrayPool<T>` to recycle arrays, instead allocating it.

Comment: @aepot Thanks for the reply. I've moved to array instead of List, and it seems like it has improved the speed a bit. However, instead of doing the `XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement` and so on, I can use `reader.ReadSubtree()` which gave a huge speed improvement. It's about 40% faster now

Comment: @MortenMoulder Why don't use proper dedicated tools to profile and measure. `Stopwatch` is not dedicated for performance measurement. Have you tried [Benchmark.net](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet)?

Comment: @PeterCsala Oh I know Stopwatch isn't exactly the best, but when we're talking 10+ seconds, it's fine for that. I don't exactly need perfect "how much faster is it". I just need "is it faster or not"

Comment: How long does the deserialization to Model take?

Comment: I would get rid of `XmlSerializer` and `XElement`. I would manually take the data from the `XmlReader` and populate the model.

Comment: And, of course, saving to the database should be done in a separate thread. So that the parsing thread doesn't wait.